# Does increasing the number of columns in group by change result - SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, group

I was wondering if adding more columns in group by change result/output of selected fields in SQL? For instance, below both queries are same except I just two additional columns i.e., quarter and week and the results are changing for the total of "sent" column for August 2022 if we see that in an excel. Like I am just including the week and quarter columns.

Query 1 output is something else, while query 2 output is different - it's just that I have added two additional columns i.e., week and quarter but it shouldn't affect the total sum of any column, right? The sum of sent for august 2022 in query 1 is 48k while for query 2 its 47k - which I don't understand why its happening.

**Query 1:**

```
-- 1 (query 1)


SELECT

template,
url,   
,EXTRACT(year FROM date) AS year
,EXTRACT(month FROM date) AS month

,COUNT(distinct(email_template)) as Email_Templates
,count(CASE WHEN action = 'Sent' then id else NULL end) as sent

,count(CASE when action = 'Bounce' then id else NULL end) as bounces
,bounces/sent as bounce_ratio

FROM table

WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM date) = 2022 
and EXTRACT(month FROM date) = 08

GROUP BY
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

**Query 2:**

```
-- 2 (query 2)


SELECT

template,
url,
,EXTRACT(year FROM date) AS year
,EXTRACT(quarter FROM date) AS quarter
,EXTRACT(month FROM date) AS month
,EXTRACT(week FROM date) AS week

,COUNT(distinct(email_template)) as Email_Templates
,count(CASE WHEN action = 'Sent' then id else NULL end) as sent

,count(CASE when action = 'Bounce' then id else NULL end) as bounces
,bounces/sent as bounce_ratio

FROM table

WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM activity_date) = 2022 
and EXTRACT(month FROM activity_date) = 08

GROUP BY
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: What is the difference between grouping by month or grouping by week? That should explain the difference.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen Yeah but when I am filtering the results based on August 2022 in an excel, both queries should give me same result, right? Isn't it?

Comment: You’re not filtering here, you’re grouping. They are very different. `WHERE` is filtering part

Comment: Yes. Changing the number of columns changes the results. There's a difference between GROUP BY and WHERE.

Comment: @KenWhite So, what should I do in both queries so that their output matches? I need to have the results available by quarter, week, year and month; and I don't want to write each individual query sepeately for week, month, quarter, and year. So, what should I do in that case then?

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen by filtering i mean that i am doing it in excel and seeing the results for august month. so, what should i do to get the results matched and get all information for week, month, quarter, and year instead of writing each separate query for all scenarios.

Comment: You can't do it in a single query, because the queries are asking for different things. I can't tell you how to treat cancer, heart disease and diabetes in a single post, because they're different diseases, and the periods week, month, quarter and year are separate time frames.

Comment: @Fiz Why would you want to know weeks if you want to group by month? How would that work? “Give me the number of things in august but also their weeks but not separate but as a whole” makes no sense

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Actually, I also need trailing 6 - 8 individual weeks' data as well. And also in my report, I need to show data by all months too. So, what is the ideal way to get that if you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To add a column to the `group by` clause doesn't change the result per se. It depends on how the groupings relate.

If you query data from within a specific year and group it by months you will (probably) get 12 rows as output. When you add the quarter to the grouping you will still get the same result, because all dates in a month are in the same quarter.

If you query the data by week you will get 52 rows. If you add the month to your grouping, you will get more rows, because a week might span two months (like week #39 starts in September and ends in October).

Comment: So, you would suggest not adding the week into the filter then? Or what should I do with week or put some days interval into the week so that it doesn't spread across the multiple months?

Comment: No, I don't. You asked whether changing the columns in `group by` affects your result and I just answered this question. I'd suggest you think about, what is required by your business case and then supply the corresponding query/queries. If you have multiple different requirements, you will have to live with multiple queries and multiple answers (as Sami Kuhmonen already commented on your question).

Comment: The different sums (47k vs. 48k) are not caused by different groupings. They have to be equal if the everything else on the query is the same. It's just the no of rows in the result, which are affected. In my week-month-example, you might have a result 500 for week #39 in the week-only query and a result result of 370 for #39 & September + 130 for #39 & October.
So maybe your calculation differs. But this is not part of the sql as you don't have a `sum` calculated in your queries.